# freemarker base and derived ftl;s

Tags: java, freemarker

I want to ask if object oriented is supported in free marker language.
If I have

```
Base.ftl
{
@Generalmacro
 {
   @derived
 }
}

Derived1.ftl include Base.ftl
{
@Generalmacro

@derived

}

Derived2.ftl include Base.ftl
{
@Generalmacro
@derived
}
```

Is there option to call derived1 and derived2 from the base.ftl like abstract method that each derived ftl need to define.

Answer (score 0):

While FreeMarker doesn't support OOP or any kind of template/macro inheritance, what you want to achieve (if I understand it well) is possible. You can have a call to the yet undefined @derived macro in @generalmacro, and then define @derived in another file, where you #include the file that defines and then calls @generalmacro.